# Does Windows Phone provide Enterprise Administration like Apple?

Tags: windows, iphone, windows-phone

As Apple provided [Mobile Device Management](http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/integration/mdm/) for enterprise device management, does Windows provide the similar functionality as we all know Windows Phone 7 provides more security features than Apple iPhone.

Comment: You may want to read up on the content provided at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8842

Comment: After reading the content it appears that the phone is managed via Exchange ActiveSync policies.

Comment: @todda.speot.is this qualifies as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft make some good high-level material available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8842) that explains the device is managed via Exchange. Functionality like remote-wipe is also part of this Exchange management.

There is no Mobile Device Management equivalent for Windows Phone 7. There also appears no ability to lock down social network integration or application installations. See [this TechNet video](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/Video/gg405039) and the commentary for discussion about this.